# set dynamic value and text of select box

Tags: jquery

i have a select box at my page , i want to set diffrent value and text in select based on page login info. how is it possible with jquery

Comment: more info please, and can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

for selections, all you would have to do is this.  Assume the id of the selection is name

```
$('#name').val(10);
```

val is the value of the option you would like to be selected